# Search Field. How to code: If you cannot find a value

Tags: jquery, search, filter, negation

I wrote this JS Code

```js
$("#itemSearch").on("keyup", function () {

  if ($("#itemSearch").val().trim() == '') {
    $(".card-content").show();
  }

  else {
    var value = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase() ;
      $(".card-group").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  }
});
```

and want to say something like:

```js
$(".card-group"):not.text()
alert ("1");
```

or

```js
$(".card-group").text ! value
alert("1");
```

Can anybody help maybe?

Greetings
Erya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer now. It works with include()!

```
$("#itemSearch").on("keyup", function() {

if ($("#itemSearch").val() == '') {
  $(".card-content").show();
  showPage(1);
  $(".pagination").css("display", "flex");
}

else {

var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$(".card-group").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
});

$(".pagination").css("display", "none");

**if ($(".card-group").text().toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
  alert ("1");
}
else {
  alert ("2");
}**

}

});
```